# Conditional insert statement in SQL

Tags: sql

I have an `INSERT` statement where I need to populate one column `emp_id` from another table. My SQL looks something like the below but does not work.

Any help would be appreciated. Please note that this is just an independent SQL and not part of any plsql.

```
 INSERT INTO employee_demo (emp_id, emp_name, salary, created_by, created_dt, status) 
     SELECT
         emp_id 
     FROM 
         employee 
     WHERE 
         emp_country IN ('Austria', 'Belgium', 'France', 'Spain'), 'John Brown', '10000', 2, sysdate, 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO employee_demo (emp_id, emp_name, salary, created_by, created_dt, status) 
    select emp_id, 'John Brown', '10000', 2, sysdate, 'A' 
    from employee where emp_country IN('Austria', 'Belgium', 'France', 'Spain');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
INSERT INTO employee_demo (emp_id, emp_name, salary, created_by, created_dt, status) 
select emp_id, 'John Brown' as emp_name, 10000 as salary, 2 as created_by, sysdate as created_dt, 'A' as status from employee where emp_country IN('Austria', 'Belgium', 'France', 'Spain');
```